# What kind of authorization I have to use on deployment server with gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

I have laravel application. My deployment on server looks like:

1. from server git pull new code from private gitlab repository
2. docker-compose pull new image from private gitlab private container registry.

What right way to authorize from server to pull code and image from gitlab private repository?
Should I use access token? because now I just authorized with my developer username/password account/

Answer (score 0):

Use a [deploy token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/index.html) or [project access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html) with required scope to read the repository/registry

To clone a repo:

```bash
git clone "https://gitlab-ci-token:${your_project_token}@gitlab.example.com/path/to/repo.git"
```

To auth to the registry:

```bash
docker login -u ${DEPLOY_TOKEN_NAME} -p ${DEPLOY_TOKEN} registry.example.com
docker pull registry.example.com/group/project/image:tag
```